# Adjoint differential equations - Relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

In my ODE book (ODE by Wolfgang Walter), I have this exercise.

> Let $G(x)$ be a fundamental matrix of
> $$
> y^{\prime}=A(x) y .
> $$
> Show that $\left(G(x)^{-1}\right)^{\top}$ is a fundamental matrix of
> $$
> z^{\prime}=-A(x)^{\top} z.
> $$

I solved this Problem, but I can still leave it here open as a puzzle.

Comment: Which book is it?